# Does the DLT-19 Heavy Blaster have any advantage over the RT-97C?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

In the wikia entry for [RT-97C Heavy Blaster](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/RT-97C_Heavy_Blaster) it says:

> The RT-97C outclasses the [DLT-19 Heavy Blaster](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/DLT-19_Heavy_Blaster) in every way, making
>   it a critical upgrade for any players that prefer using rapid-fire
>   heavy blasters as their primary weapon.

But that seems kind of crazy, every other blaster in the game has a situation where its useful.  Why would the game developers and staff spend the time making a model and coding it, only for it to be the one useless blaster in the game?

I notice that some blasters lose accuracy the faster they are fired, but that stat isn't recorded anywhere.  Perhaps the DLT-19 maintains more accuracy while firing?

Is the DLT-19 Heavy Blaster totally inferior to the RT-97C?

Once someone unlocks the RT-97C is there any game advantage to using the DLT-19?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:

[Why choose the DLT-19 over the RT-97C?](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsBattlefront/comments/3s9tly/why_choose_the_dlt19_over_the_rt97c/), *Reddit - Battlefront subreddit*

> I think it's right to say that RT-97C is more powerful and has tighter
> spread (starting and maximum). In theory it will drop a DLT-19 user if
> both go at each other from 10 m. However, it's looks more like a
> burst-fire weapon at medium range. It gets less accurate quicker than
> DLT-19 per shot, but it stabilises quicker too. Has minimal side to
> side and bigger upwards kick than DLT-19.
>
> DLT-19 looks like the more 'spray and pray' weapon of the two (there's
> just no real penalty from holding down the trigger), with slower
> spread build up and less of a upward kick, thus feels more predictable
> and reliable. RT-97C has a bit more damage (1 'blast' less on average,
> assuming you stay on target) meaning you can come up victorious in CQC
> if you learn to control it and it offers great accuracy as long as you
> keep tap-firing it.
>
> I've got the RT-97C yesterday and I'm sort of getting the hang of it.
> As long as I manage to control I can win with DLT-19 users in 1 v 1
> and drop targets that I would find difficult with DLT-19 at longer
> range. However, one small mistake and you will easily miss a 'blast'
> or two that wouldn't happen with the DLT-19. It's definitely good and
> if you're willing to master it you will give you a slight edge over
> DLT-19.
>
> Great statistic to remember:
>
> ***Base spread***
>
>  **DLT-19 - 0.5**
>
>  **RT-97C - 0.1**
>
> ***With spread per shot:***
>
> **DLT-19 - 0.025**
>
> **RT-97C - 0.15**
>
> So RT-97C has amazing accuracy with the first few shots, but after
> that it can easily get more inaccurate, but will not go over 1.0
> (which it will reach after 6 hots). DLT-19 will go to a maximum of
> 1.475 without start cards (max is 2.0, but it goes up by 0.975 after 39 shots before overheating from the base of 0.5), meaning that
> overall RT-97C should be considered more accurate, but it increases
> the spread much faster.

I own the game but I really don't play that much, but I can say that the RT-97C is better than the DLT-19 in terms of rapid fire when shooting.

But DLT-19 is a good starter blaster.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this on the [DLT-19](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/RT-97C_Heavy_Blaster) wikia page:

> It should also be noted that currently, the DLT-19 is outclassed in
>   most categories by the RT-97C Heavy Blaster, possessing inferior
>   damage, zoom, and spread, however the DLT-19 has much less vertical
>   recoil, and is much more accurate.

Commenters on a [reddit post for this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsBattlefront/comments/4az8wa/does_the_dlt19_heavy_blaster_have_any_advantage/) have mentioned that the DLT-19 is better for mid to long range combat and the RT-97C is better for mid to close range.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put at this in "real weapon terms". The DLT-19 is like the M16, and the RT-97c is like a flak gun. The first is more for anti infantry at close range, and the second is for long range or, rarely, anti-air.

Comment: Those two examples seem so far apart compared to how close the two guns are that I'm not sure it works.

Comment: The DLT-19 has no scope but it maintains accuracy better during prolonged firing than the RT-97c, which can make the DLT-19 better for some sniping situations.  The lack of accuracy during extended firing forces a RT-97c shooter to use burst fire rather than auto to hit far away targets.